# How to Handle Recursively Nested Components in RivetsJS?

Tags: javascript, recursion, rivets.js, javascript-databinding

I currently have a Model that is related back to itself in a parent-child relationship. I need to be able to display these in a tree-like structure on the page (i.e. Nested `<li>` items). Each `<li>` item will have an underlying HTML structure that has various data-binding and event handlers (all implemented with [Rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/)).

My initial thought is to create a [component](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#components) with Rivets.js, and then just nest it within itself. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around how these would be initialized and inserted into the DOM.

Here is what I would like to be able to do:

```
/** DATA LAYER **/
var item = {
    id: 1,
    title: "test item 1",
    description: "my description 1",
    someHandler: function () {
        console.log("handle something for Item 1");
    },
    items: [
        {
            id: 2,
            parentItem: 1,
            title: "test item 2",
            description: "my description 2",
            someHandler: function () {
                console.log("handle something for Item 2");
            },
            items: [

            ]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            parentItem: 1,
            title: "test item 3",
            description: "my description 3",
            someHandler: function () {
                console.log("handle something for Item 3");
            },
            items: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    parentItem: 3,
                    title: "test item 4",
                    description: "my description 4",
                    someHandler: function () {
                        console.log("handle something for Item 4");
                    },
                    items: [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

And the presentation layer:

```
/** TEMPLATE **/
<div id="item_template"> <!-- accessed via <my-new-item></my-new-item> in HTML -->
    <li>
        <h4 rv-text="title"></h4>
        <p rv-html="description"></p>
        <button rv-click="someHandler">Click Me!</button>
        <ol>
            <my-new-item rv-each-item="items" item="item"></my-new-item>
        </ol>
    </li>
</div>
```

And the business layer:

```
rivets.components['my-new-item'] = {
  template: function() {
    return document.querySelector('#item_template').innerHTML;
  },
  initialize: function(el, data) {
    return data;
  }
}

rivets.init('my-new-item', document.querySelector('#page'), item);
```

Is there a way to recursively nest components in RivetsJS?

**UPDATE**

I've put together a jsfiddle to illustrate this. I can't seem to get the data-binding to work during the recursion.

https://jsfiddle.net/0mv4r8w0/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the solution is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0mv4r8w0/5/

Apparently, I need to explicitly define a property to access the data.

The template changes to (note that I'm using `item.*` to access properties now):

```
<div id="item_template">
    <li>
        <h4 rv-text="item.title"></h4>
        <p rv-html="item.description"></p>
        <button rv-on-click="item.someHandler">Click Me!</button>
        <ol>
            <my-new-item rv-each-item="item.items" item="item"></my-new-item>
        </ol>
    </li>
</div>
```

and the `rivits.init` call changes to (note the data is set to a property now):

```
rivets.init('my-new-item', document.querySelector('#page'), { item: item });
```